# Visual Studio equivalent to Delphi ctrl+t

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What's is the equivalent visual studio keys shortcut to delphi ctrl+t?
In delphi, this shortcut removes all spaces from caret position to the next non spcace character, including return and line break codes.

Comment: Haven't been able to find one for VS, but thanks for the tip about Delphi's shortcut!

Comment: @DaveNottage; That key combination depends on the keyboard emulation you're using in the IDE. See [Keyboard Mappings Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Keyboard_Mappings_Index)

Comment: You are right Ken, Ctrl+T works on IDE Classic Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove return and line break codes, you can use the [JoinLines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JamesASinclair.JoinLines) extension.

Comment: Thank you Sergey.